# How does the gravitational field behave inside a star?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, density

The interior gravitational field of a star with constant density is given by

$ds^{2}=-\left(\frac{P_{c}+\rho_{0}}{P(r)+\rho_{0}}\right)^{2}dt^{2}+\frac{dr^{2}}{1-\frac{8\pi\rho_{0}}{3}r^{2}}+r^{2}d\theta^{2}+r^{2}\sin\theta^{2}d\phi^{2}$

Where $P_{c}$ is the pressure at the centre of the star, $\rho_0$ is the density of the star and $P(r)$ is the pressure at point $r$.

My question is does the $dr^{2}$ component $\left({1-\frac{8\pi\rho_{0}}{3}r^{2}}\right)^{-1}$ ever change sign as we go from the center of the star to the surface or does it always stay the same sign.

Comment: The metric always has a Minkowski signature. So you know the sign can't change. So are you asking *why* it doesn't change?

Comment: @Timaeus There could be a coordinate singularity, indicating something like the presence of an event horizon. This is the case for Schwarzschild, and I guess one could expect such a coordinate singularity to appear, if using coordinates like the OP's for gravitational collapse.

Comment: @RobinEkman A coordinate singularity merely indicates the boundary of a coordinate chart, it has absolutely zero physical significance. It could be an indicator of something physical if you were trying to make a large chart. But you could take a portion of flat Minkowksi spacetime and pick a coordinate system on it that has a coordibate singularity on the boundary. It means nothing.

Comment: @Timaeus Yes, but what I was getting as it that your conclusion that the sign of the $dr^2$ component can't change is too strong.

Comment: @RobinEkman It doesn't change in the domain of the chart which needs to be on one side or the other of any coordinate singularity. For instance you can use Schwarzschild inside or you can use Schwarzschild outside, but Schwarzschild coordinates don't apply at the horizon events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, it does change sign when $r_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi\rho_{0}}}$

Perhaps a more interesting question is "why is this?"  Well, we know that the exterior of the star has to be the Schwarzschild Metric, since this is the unique spherically symmetric vacuum solution with zero charge.  Consequently, we know, at the surface radius $R$:

$$1-\frac{2M}{R} = \left(\frac{P_{c} + \rho}{P(R) + \rho}\right)^{2}$$

and

$$1-\frac{2M}{R} = 1 - \frac{8\pi\rho}{3}R^{2}$$

Solving the second equation for $M$:

$$M = \frac{4\pi \rho R^{3}}{3}$$

putting this into the first equation:

$$1-\frac{8\pi\rho R^{2}}{3} = \left(\frac{P_{c} + \rho}{P(R) + \rho}\right)^{2}$$

But, on our first step, we worked out the value $r_{0}$ for our sign change to be equal to $r_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi\rho_{0}}}$, so this really is:

$$1-\left(\frac{R}{r_{0}}\right)^{2} = \left(\frac{P_{c} + \rho}{P(R) + \rho}\right)^{2}$$

It should be clear that the right hand side of this equation is always positive and nonzero, so if $R$, the surface of our star, is ever larger than $r_{0}$, then there is no solution for our system of equations.  What does that mean?  Well, there's a theorem, that if you ever fit a mass $M$ inside of a sphere of radius $2M$, then it is impossible to have a stable body, and collapse to a black hole has to happen.  But, every time I add a sliver of radius $dR$ to the surface of a constant-volume star, I increase the radius by an amount $dR$, but I increase the volume (and therefore the mass, since it is constant density) by an amount $4\pi R^{2}dR$.  Therefore, the mass will grow faster than the radius, and once I let the radius get sufficiently large, no matter what the central density, I have eventually put a mass $M$ inside of a schwarzschild radius, the matter distribution is no longer stable, and I get a black hole.

That is what your sign change is yelling out at you about.

Comment: Note that I dislike this argument, because it requires $P(R) > P_{c}$ to work.  At the time of this writing, it's not clear to me whether this is a problem with the original metric, or my failure to apply the correct junction conditions, which would place an infinitely dense shell of matter at the surface of the star.

Comment: Can you please give me a formula for the curvature at the center? So I can see in the math that it is not zero?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei: Einstein's eqation tells us $R_{ab} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{ab} = 8\pi T_{ab}$, and $T_{0}{}^{0} =\rho$, so you can work it out.