# What is the metric at the center of a star?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, astrophysics, metric-tensor, stellar-physics

If there is only one star in the universe then is the metric at the center of the star flat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:[What is the general relativity explanation for why objects at the center of the Earth are weightless?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219897/)

Comment: My answer to the question I've linked about discusses the [interior metric](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=interior+metric) for a star and gives a detailed account of the simplified case of uniform density. There are also lots of other Q/As that discuss [the interior metric](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=interior+metric).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241548/2451